# contact_us gem not mailing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, contact-form

I'm just trying to send email from within my application. For some reason, the email isn't being sent. Am I missing a step? Here is the `contact_us` documentation. I followed it exactly. https://github.com/jdutil/contact_us. How can I get it to mail?

Here is my view:

```
<div class="container">
  <h2><%= t('.contact_us') %></h2>
  <%= simple_form_for @contact, :url => contacts_path do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :name, :label => t('.name') if ContactUs.require_name %>
    <%= f.input :email, :label => t('.email') %>
    <%= f.input :subject, :label => t('.subject') if ContactUs.require_subject %>
    <%= f.input :message, :as => :text, :label => t('.message') %>
    <%= f.button :submit, :value => t('.submit'), :alt => t('.submit'), :id => 'contact_us_contact_submit', :title => t('.submit') %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

I also set `config.mailer_to = "drichards2013@gmail.com."`

When I submit the form, I receive a notification that the email was successfully sent.

Comment: `"drichards2013@gmail.com.com"`??

Comment: That was just a typo. My code has one .com